# TreeView как перехватить и отменить выделение нового пункта?

Tags: wpf, treeview

Здравствуйте.
Имею TreeView с событием SelectedItemChanged. 
Необходимо (в случае определенного условия) выдать пользователю MessageBox "Продолжить? Да/Нет" и **если пользователь нажал Нет** - оставить выделенным предыдущий пункт.

Пробовал вот так:
(но в результате получается какая то каша, treeView1_SelectedItemChanged вызывается 3 и в treeView1.SelectedItem то пункт к которому мы хотели перейти то пункт который был, и потом снова новый)

```
MyClass kash_item;
private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Перейти?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            kash_item = treeView1.SelectedItem as MyClass; //сохраняю то что было выделено этим кликом
            //*выполнить что то*
            break;
        case MessageBoxResult.No:
            kash_item.IsSelected = true; //пытаюсь вернуть обратно то что было выделено раньше
            break;
    }
}
```

Подскажите как решить мою задачу?

Comment: А что такое `MyClass`?

Comment: Мой класс, привязывающийся к пунктам treeView.
Имеет поля: Name и IsSelected

Comment: Тип "Мой класс", используюется для описания каждого из пунктов TreeView в привязанной коллекции к treeView1 (treeView1.ItemsSourc).
Имеет поля: Name и IsSelected, привязаны в XAML

Comment: А как именно привязано к XAML? Дайте воспроизводящий пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что у вас метод `treeView1_SelectedItemChanged` вызывается рекурсивно. Проще всего оказалось выполнить его на следующей итерации цикла сообщений, и запомнить устанавливаемый элемент, чтобы не показывать лишний `MessageBox`:

```
MyClass expected_item;
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var oldItem = (MyClass)e.OldValue;
    var newItem = (MyClass)e.NewValue;

    if (newItem == expected_item)
        return;
    expected_item = null;

    MessageBoxResult result =
        MessageBox.Show("Перейти?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    switch (result)
    {
    case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
        break;
    case MessageBoxResult.No:
        expected_item = oldItem;
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => oldItem.IsSelected = true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не заработало к сожалению...

Comment: @trancer1019: Ага, понял. Смотрите обновление ответа.